# How to keep a modal open in rails if validation error is raised

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I am a bit confused about how I can re-render a bootstrap modal (a form) if it raises a validation error for the form?

**Goal**

I am currently trying to create a new store via a modal.

**Issues**

- I am encountering an issue whereby my modal containing a form is not showing up when I click the button. *~ The new.js.erb file is reached, as I am able to render a flash message (instead of a form).~*
- My  tag lightens up in my browser when I click the button and the new.js.erb and the form partial are rendered. Therefore, I also attached my views/layouts/application.html.erb file and my console log with the rendered files.

**Console log of files rendered when pressing new button:**

```
Rendering stores/new.js.erb
  Rendered stores/_age_table_fields.html.erb (5.8ms)
  Rendered stores/_age_table_fields.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered stores/_form.html.erb (32.0ms)
  Rendered stores/new.js.erb (34.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 47.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

**Code**

views/stores/index.html.erb

```
<%= render "partials/show_panel_stores_overview"%>
```

views/partials/show_panel_stores_overview.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'New store', new_store_path, remote: true %>
```

views/stores/new.js.erb

```
var form = $("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
var wrapper = $('<div>').attr('id', 'new-store-form').append(form);
$('body').append(wrapper);
```

views/stores/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for (Store.new) do |f|%>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.button :submit%>
```

store controller

```
def new
    @store = current_user.store.build
    @store.age_tables.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Page not accessible' }
      format.js
    end
    authorize @store

  end

  def create
    @store = current_user.stores.create(store_params)
    authorize @store
    if @store.save
      redirect_to stores_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

views/layouts.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>TODO</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %> <!-- Uncomment if you import CSS in app/javascript/packs/application.js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When your form is rendered on the 'index' page it requires the `@store` variable to be assigned in the 'index' action of the controller.

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @store = current_user.stores.build
    # ...
  end
end
```

For you to be able to rerender the modal, the form should send an Ajax request when submitted. Use `remote: true` for that

`<%= simple_form_for (@store, remote: true) do |f|%>`

**Updated**

Now as you have shown that you have the `new.js.erb` file and the form is rendered by a separate '/new' request, we can see that you actually don't need to assign the `@store` variable in the `index` action. Instead, in order to avoid errors, you don't have to render the form on the 'index' page (when the 'index' page is rendered) as you did before.

Add an empty `div` on the index page where your form will be render by the 'new.js.erb' script.

```
<div id="new-store-form"></div>
```

The 'new.js.erb' script should work for both cases:

1. Rendering new form (the 'new' action)
2. Re-rendering the form when it is invalid (the 'create' action).

views/stores/new.js.erb

```
$("#new-store-form").html("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
```

You will probably need not only render the modal, but also open it.

```
  $("#modal_id").modal('show');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The index actions is `def index @user = current_user
    @stores = current_user.stores end `

Comment: So what? Did you add @store there?

Comment: Corrected it and added an `@store` in the index action. `@store` can now indeed be used in the form, leaving only the re-render modal question to solve..

Comment: Do you have 'new.js.erb' file?